# CasperJS times out on a page that Chrome can load in much less time. Is this expected?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, performance-testing, casperjs

I'm using casperjs 1.1.0-beta3 to measure page load times of a CPU and data intensive web page. In some scenarios, I'm seeing that casperjs is taking a very long time to detect the test-hook that I have put in place to indicate that the page has finished loading and processing the large amount of data.

The test hook uses the `casper.waitFor` function to look for a variable that gets set in global scope on the page. This is what indicates to the script that everything is complete and rendered.

Details of what the page does is not not very relevant, other than to say that the it gets a large amount of JSON data from a server and the processing is done on the main thread -- no worker threads involved and no CORS requests either.

The issue is, casperjs seems to take a lot more time (10x +) compared to the identical scenario running on regular chrome.

What might be going on? What are some ways to debug?

I have setup casperjs scripts to take a screenshot of the page when it times out, and it shows that the page is still in a 'processing' state. So it indeed looks like the webkit engine used by casper is much slower than normal chrome.

Comment: If you say *in some scenarios*, do you mean different data or partially different code? Register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: From my point of view, speed rendered page is too aleatory (relative to a standard browser -I have often small casper freeze-) to measure accurate page load times. But if you reach the timeout, it means there is something wrong with the scenario, you might be stuck in a step. You can also use casper options to debug : `casper.options.verbose = true;` `casper.options.logLevel ="debug";`